# Looping through text elements and replacing strings

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I would like subtitute the variables (in brackets) in the AgreementTexts with values of the same named elements (without brackets of course) in the XML.

Can anybody help me how to do this?
thanks!
Adam

This is my XML:

```
<MailBody>
  <MSG_BOComment_PDF type="string" /> 
  <HSH_Is_Migrated type="string">NO</HSH_Is_Migrated> 
  <PDFC_X_Cust type="string">7990122189</PDFC_X_Cust> 
  <PDFC_X_FOBO_Id type="string">68281 / 41080</PDFC_X_FOBO_Id> 
  <PDFC_RPDealTradTime type="dateTime">06/04/2010 11:32:00</PDFC_RPDealTradTime> 
  <MSG_ConfTypeDE type="string">DEUTSCH</MSG_ConfTypeDE> 
  <MSG_ConfTypeEN type="string">ENGLISH</MSG_ConfTypeEN> 
  <Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2>
  <LINE_ON>
  <AgreementText type="string">The Buyer agrees that [MSG_ConfTypeDE], for the purpose of paragraph 8(a) of the Agreement, bonds that, in the determination of the Buyer (acting reasonably), meet each of the following criteria, shall be eligible as New Purchased Securities:</AgreementText> 
  </LINE_ON>
  <LINE_ON>
  <AgreementText type="string">(1) EITHER: Test+</AgreementText> 
  </LINE_ON>
  <LINE_ON>
  <AgreementText type="string">(A) The bonds [PDFC_X_FOBO_Id] have the of a grandfathered guarantee (Gew?tr?rhaftung) from, or are issued by, the Federal Re-public of Germany or one of its constituent States (L?er) and are rated by at least two of Fitch Ratings Inc, Moody? Investors Service, Inc</AgreementText> 
  </LINE_ON>
  <LINE_ON>
  <AgreementText type="string">OR+</AgreementText> 
  </LINE_ON>
  <LINE_ON>
  <AgreementText type="string">(B) The bonds are issued by LFAF??rbank Bayern and are guaranteed by the State of Bavaria and are rated at least one Rating Agency and</AgreementText> 
  </LINE_ON>
  <LINE_ON>
  <AgreementText type="string">(2) The bonds are [PDFC_X_FOBO_Id] denominated in Euro.</AgreementText> 
  </LINE_ON>
  </Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2>
  <MSG_EntC_EmailTo type="string">mmfx.backoffice@hsh-nordbank.com</MSG_EntC_EmailTo> 
  <MSG_C_Address1 type="string" /> 
  <MSG_C_Address2 type="string">ML Financial Centre</MSG_C_Address2> 
  <MSG_C_Address3 type="string">2 King Edward Street</MSG_C_Address3> 
  <MSG_C_Address4 type="string">LONDON EC1A 1HQ|GROSSBRITANNIEN</MSG_C_Address4> 
  <MSG_C_ContactName type="string">Merrill Lynch International</MSG_C_ContactName> 
  <MSG_EntC_Address1 type="string">Transaction Services</MSG_EntC_Address1> 
  <MSG_EntC_FaxAddress type="string">+49 431 900 34082</MSG_EntC_FaxAddress> 
  <MSG_EntC_PhoneNumber type="string">+49 431 900 11428</MSG_EntC_PhoneNumber> 
  <MSG_EntC_Address2 type="string">OE 3651 Geld- und Devisenabwicklung</MSG_EntC_Address2> 
  <MSG_EntC_Address3 type="string">Martensdamm 6</MSG_EntC_Address3> 
  <MSG_EntC_Address4 type="string">24103 Kiel</MSG_EntC_Address4> 
  <MSG_EntC_ContactName type="string">HSH Nordbank AG</MSG_EntC_ContactName> 
  <EVT_EventDate type="date">06/04/2010</EVT_EventDate> 
  <MSG_ConfTypeEN type="string" /> 
  <MUR type="string">KTPP86425</MUR> 
  <MailHeader_Id type="int">86425</MailHeader_Id> 
</MailBody>
```

After implementing Flynn'S solution I got this output. But this not exactly what I want.
I get before and after AgreementText values of elements in the same order from XML...

> NO 7990122189 68281 / 41080 06/04/2010
>   11:32:00 DEUTSCH ENGLISH The Buyer
>   agrees that DEUTSCH, for the purpose
>   of paragraph 8(a) of the Agreement,
>   bonds that, in the determination of
>   the Buyer (acting reasonably), meet
>   each of the following criteria, shall
>   be eligible as New Purchased
>   Securities:
>
> (1) EITHER: Test+
>
> (A) The bonds 68281 / 41080 have the
>   of a grandfathered guarantee
>   (Gew?tr?rhaftung) from, or are issued
>   by, the Federal Re-public of Germany
>   or one of its constituent States
>   (L?er) and are rated by at least two
>   of Fitch Ratings Inc, Moody? Investors
>   Service, Inc
>
> OR+
>
> (B) The bonds are issued by
>   LFAF??rbank Bayern and are guaranteed
>   by the State of Bavaria and are rated
>   at least one Rating Agency and
>
> (2) The bonds are 68281 / 41080
>   denominated in Euro.
>
> mmfx.backoffice@hsh-nordbank.com ML
>   Financial Centre 2 King Edward Street
>   LONDON EC1A 1HQ| GROSSBRITANNIEN
>   Merrill Lynch International
>   Transaction Services +49 431 900 34082
>   +49 431 900 11428 OE 3651 Geld- und Devisenabwicklung Martensdamm 6 24103
>   Kiel HSH Nordbank AG 06/04/2010
>   KTPP86425 86425

This is my expected output: Only the [Variables.in.brackets] in the AgreementText's should be substituted with values of same name elements in XML.

> The Buyer agrees that DEUTSCH, for the
>   purpose of paragraph 8(a) of the
>   Agreement, bonds that, in the
>   determination of the Buyer (acting
>   reasonably), meet each of the
>   following criteria, shall be eligible
>   as New Purchased Securities:
>
> (1) EITHER: Test+
>
> (A) The bonds 68281 / 41080 have the
>   of a grandfathered guarantee
>   (Gew?tr?rhaftung) from, or are issued
>   by, the Federal Re-public of Germany
>   or one of its constituent States
>   (L?er) and are rated by at least two
>   of Fitch Ratings Inc, Moody? Investors
>   Service, Inc
>
> OR+
>
> (B) The bonds are issued by
>   LFAF??rbank Bayern and are guaranteed
>   by the State of Bavaria and are rated
>   at least one Rating Agency and
>
> (2) The bonds are 68281 / 41080
>   denominated in Euro.

This is my xsl file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">
  <xsl:key name="vars" match="*" use="name()" /> 
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="single_page" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-left="25mm" margin-bottom="10mm" margin-right="13mm" margin-top="7mm">
  <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" /> 
  <fo:region-after region-name="page-numbering" extent="15mm" /> 
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="repeatable_master">
  <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="single_page" maximum-repeats="10" /> 
  </fo:page-sequence-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="repeatable_master">
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
  <xsl:call-template name="MailBody" /> 
  </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="MailBody">
  <fo:table font-size="10.00pt" width="170.00mm">
  <fo:table-column column-width="170mm" /> 
  <fo:table-body>
  <fo:table-row height="1mm">
  <fo:table-cell>
  <fo:block>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" /> 
  </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2/LINE_ON/AgreementText/text()" name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="text" select="." /> 
  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($text,'[')">
  <xsl:variable name="varname" select="substring-before(substring-after($text,'['),']')" /> 
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'[')" /> 
  <xsl:value-of select="key('vars',$varname)" /> 
  <xsl:call-template name="replace">
  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,']')" /> 
  </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:value-of select="$text" /> 
  <fo:block space-after="10px" /> 
  </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry for multiple editing, wrong usage as I'm totally newbie here ;))

Comment: So the first AgreementText would read: he Buyer agrees that DEUTSCH, for the purpose of paragraph 8(a) ENGLISH of the Agreement, bonds that, in the determination of the Buyer DEUTSCH (acting reasonably), meet each of the following criteria, shall be eligible as New Purchased Securities: ? (No, that's not it, or?)

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here

Comment: I also cannot parse the question.  Maybe an example would help, with a *before* and an *after* view of the XML document.

Comment: I modified the question.. I think, it's more clearer now.

Comment: I think substitution works fine. I just want to eliminate the **NO 7990122189 68281 / 41080 06/04/2010 11:32:00 DEUTSCH ENGLISH**  at the beginning and **mmfx.backoffice@hsh-nordbank.com ML Financial Centre 2 King Edward Street LONDON EC1A 1HQ| GROSSBRITANNIEN Merrill Lynch International Transaction Services +49 431 900 34082 +49 431 900 11428 OE 3651 Geld- und Devisenabwicklung Martensdamm 6 24103 Kiel HSH Nordbank AG 06/04/2010 KTPP86425 86425**  at the end. This values are the values of the elements in source xml..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="vars" match="*" use="name()" />

  <xsl:template match="Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2/LINE_ON/AgreementText/text()" name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,'[')">
        <xsl:variable name="varname" select="substring-before(substring-after($text,'['),']')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'[')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="key('vars',$varname)" />
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,']')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key at the top isn't very efficient though, but without knowing their ancestry, there's no good way of deriving an efficient way of matching the nodes containing the values to replace.

Comment: Thnx Flynn.. This works great, but I want to substitute only the variables in the AgreementText elements.. Any idea how can i limit or filter it only for AgreementTexts?

Comment: It should already do that.. What's it matching that it shouldn't?

Comment: Just read your edit; the problem is where you call `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />`, you're actually telling it to include everything within that node, so it's going to include those. You probably want to replace it with something like `<xsl:apply-templates select='Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2' />`, or simply don't include the identity template; it's unlikely to be useful in this instance anyway.

Comment: Thank you Flynn for your reply... When I use <xsl:apply-templates select='Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2'/> it doesnt output anything. I just get a blank page... I think when variable name and node name is the same it should bypass the substitution.. That will achieve the desired result I think?!?

Comment: That's because your context node isn't the parent of 'Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2'. Selects work from the current context, in your case `/`, which is the document itself. The quick & dirty fix would be to select `.//Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2` or `*/Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2` instead (the former will work for any depth, but it's less efficient). Sorry, I didn't read your xsl in detail when I commented, I didn't notice which node was the context at the time.

Comment: It's a common misconception that `<xsl:template match="/">` and `<xsl:template match="rootnodename">` are equivalent; they're really not. The former matches the document itself, NOT any node. Looking at your code, you're probably better off replacing `<xsl:template match="/">` with a template that matches your root node, and removing the `<xsl:copy>` around the `<xsl:apply-templates ../>` call; since the document itself is the context at the moment, it's not actually copying anything anyway. If you do that, then the select I suggested earlier will work.

Comment: romoved the copy, used .//Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2 and */Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2, changed root template match to MailBody.. As a result I get either a blank page or the same result like previous!!It should not print anything, if the value from key is not in the AgreementText, in this case it is doing this, but i can't figure out where/how to limit/exclude it?!?

Comment: I don't understand why template <xsl:template match="Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2/LINE_ON/AgreementText... loop through all the elements and not only AgreementTxts?

Comment: You need to do ONE of these, not both. Either change your template match to 'MailBody', or change your apply templates to '*/Msg_SpecAgreeTxt2', not both.